# App runs on emulator, but unable to run on my device

Tags: android, android-emulator, runtime-error

I'm creating an application with image sharing elements. Everything works fine except when I try to run my app on emulator, it's unable to show the correct output as per the code. On the other hand, when I test my application on my Android device, it shows an `Unexpected Error`. I tried to restart my device and also created a new emulator, but none of them were helpful for me.

The offending code, line 55 on `FullImageActivity` is

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.full_image_view);
```

Here is the LogCat

```
04-23 05:03:07.907: W/EGL_emulation(1172): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:03:08.137: D/dalvikvm(1172): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 33K, 3% free 4846K/4952K, paused 39ms, total 40ms
04-23 05:03:10.607: W/EGL_emulation(1172): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:03:11.767: D/AndroidRuntime(1172): Shutting down VM
04-23 05:03:11.777: W/dalvikvm(1172): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a8cb90)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): Process: com.lol.meme, PID: 1172
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.lol.meme.FullImageActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(FullImageActivity.java:55)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2599)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-23 05:03:11.777: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 05:03:15.517: I/Process(1172): Sending signal. PID: 1172 SIG: 9
04-23 05:03:16.447: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 60K, 4% free 3117K/3244K, paused 27ms, total 30ms
04-23 05:03:16.707: D/(1200): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8c69818, tid 1200
04-23 05:03:16.967: W/EGL_emulation(1200): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-23 05:03:16.977: D/OpenGLRenderer(1200): Enabling debug mode 0
04-23 05:03:17.057: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 4% free 3206K/3336K, paused 21ms, total 22ms
04-23 05:03:17.127: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 3608K/3740K, paused 20ms, total 21ms
04-23 05:03:17.247: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4027K/4164K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
04-23 05:03:17.357: D/dalvikvm(1200): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 4345K/4480K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
04-23 05:03:17.447: I/Choreographer(1200): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: Please check your emulator android version and device version.

Comment: hey try using an emulator with `SD Card` option checked
and for the `Unexpected Error` check your `LogCat`.

Comment: @JaiSharma ohh well this `SD Card` thing worked but now i'am getting same error as on my device :(

Comment: post your `LogCat` so that we can help you out

Comment: whats your 55th line in `FullImageActivity.java`...

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.full_image_view);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your second argument type for resources which is an ID.
you should provide a valid argument type for this specific resource
i.e, use `R.Drawable.FILENAME`
what you are doing is that you providing the Resources an id argument which causing you an `Unexpected Error`
*Its Like fueling your petrol car with diesel :x*